# How to photograph top of Mt. Roraima

Tags: venezuela

I've seen photos of Mt. Roraima like this everywhere, wondering how can I photo a view like this in person or with drone. Is it by helicopter tour? Can I fly a drone this high launching from somewhere?

[image]

Comment: This might be a better fit for [photography.se]

Comment: I don't agree with the comment above that this belongs on photography, but I'm not sure there's much of a travel question either. Is it by helicopter tour? Sure, that's a plausible option. Can you fly a drone that high? Sure, if you have the right drone.

Comment: @ChrisH maybe there is a place one can go to get these views? i don't know, but it seems like a fair question for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

am a venezuelan so my best advice to you is to search for tourist package
like this here http://raulhelicopteros.com/galer%C3%ADa
and let them know, you need/want that service included in your trip

**!Be careful of scammers, economic situation in Venezuela is hard now and you will find a lot of people trying to get money easy, validate every source you get before paying a dime...**

[image]
http://img1.wsimg.com/isteam/ip/0e17b1ee-b057-471a-a6e2-db5177eb2604/b611817edef2f3dfde04c5771e815828.jpg/:/rs=w:400,h:500,cg:true,m/cr=w:800,h:500,a:cc